# open source web-app application, portal that triggers/redirect to real web-applications/sites

Tags: nginx, web-applications, launcher, portal

I'm looking for an open source lightweight application /panel/dashboard.
That allows me to create links/icons and so that when I click on them, I  will get redirected to the actual application within my private server

1. it has to be lightweight
2. no need for databases
3. for now just need to redirect to the actual sites/apps

something like a portal but lightweight :  here are some examples: like show the icon so that you can set the url of the actual application

[image: portal 01]

Comment: Easiest and fastest is a simple static html page. That's all you need.

Comment: Or alternatively you can use nginx rules to redirect URLs.